# Java: Which is better syntactically, for or while?

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

Simple question, possibly a duplicate but I couldn't find what I was looking for when searching.

So, which is better *syntactically*, in Java?

```
for ( ; var < 10; var++) { 
    // do something
}
```

Or ...

```
while (var < 10) {
    // do something
    var++;
 }
```

In both cases, `var` has already been initialized somewhere else. Hence, the first part of the `for` loop is empty. However, it saves one line of code.

Which is better practice, and more accepted?

**Is there somewhere better to post these type of questions?**

Comment: Opinion-based question. This is really, _really_, the same. I would personally prefer the `while`... or not. It depends.

Comment: Actually when you iterate over a definite number of items, you should always use for. Btw it's usually better practice to use extra variables for the for loops. You should not do this in an attempt to save memory.

Comment: @Tunaki I know they are the same, but just wanted to know which one was the norm or _preferred_ choice. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends entirely on the style guide you're following.

However, if you're the one coming up with a style guide, I would suggest the for loop syntax. Why? Because all of your loop constructs are right there in one line, making errors easier to spot and context easier to determine.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll stick with the `for` loop for now!